# Javascript with WebForms Syntax issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio

How do I get my instanceId recognized here ? Currently Visual Studio says 'instanceId' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. My snippet is below any help or direction would be most appreciated.'

--Jason

```html
    function ShowPrintNoTamper(instanceId) {          
                window.open('DisplayPDF.aspx?Mode=FileRoom&InstanceID='+<%= HttpUtility.UrlEncode(TamperProofStringEncode(instanceId, "F44fggjj")) %>, null, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, copyhistory=no, width=600, height=700');
            }
```

--Jason

Comment: Where do you call ShowPrintNoTamper and are you passing the instandId?

Comment: Calling it from a template column of a DataGrid....

Comment: <a id="abPDF" runat="server" visible='<%# Status(Container.DataItem) = "PDF"%>' href="#" onclick='<%# "ShowPrintNoTamper(""" & GetPdfInstanceId(Container.DataItem) & """)" %>'>
                                <img alt="View Pdf" src="images/PdfDoc.gif" /></a>